# Git hooks - How to copy files from one folder to another folder within same git branch

Tags: git, githooks

I am creating/updating files under "locales/US/en/" folder. These files should be auto copied and commit into another folder "content/en-US" with in same branch during git push/post-commit. Could you share your inputs about how to write git hooks for above requirement?

Comment: Could you add, about what you have tried already?

Comment: If these files can be autogenerated, why do they have to be under source control? Your problem should probably be solved at build or deployment time.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to do this as a pre-commit step instead of a post-commit or a post-push on the server side.

Having this as a pre-commit step will give you better control over what is actually going in every commit and will better adhere to the underlying philosophy that a git commit is a self contained  **unit of content modification** rather than some arbitrary operation on files.

Having this as part of the commit will also make it easier for you to recreate the state of your development tree (content) when you `reset`, `checkout`, etc etc.

Your pre-commit hook could be along the lines of:

```
  #!/bin/sh

  for FILE in `exec git diff-index --check --cached HEAD -- | grep 'locales/US/en'` ; do
     echo "Publishing $FILE to content/en-US"
     cp $FILE content/en-US || { echo "Failed to publish $FILE"; exit 1; }
     git add "content/en-US/$FILE" || { echo "Failed to git add content/en-US/$FILE"; exit 1; }
  done
  exit
```

Note the particularly ugly `grep` to filter for the relevant files - you can improve on that by putting the git diff-index result in a bash array and globbing for your directory and file patterns.

Also note that it will always copy the files when you try to commit. If you commit is aborted for any reason, it will attempt to copy the files again when you retry. You can of course add a check as to whether the file is present (and identical!) in the content/en-US directory to avoid copying it multiple times.